# Delete all lines including two or more same characters - Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

how to delete all lines including same characters ?

Like I want to delete from this list all words which are including aa or bb

```
aaaa
aaab
aabb
abbb
```

Comment: What should be done with lines such as `abab`, `acac`, `cabc`, `cccc` and so on?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to delete any words that have two or more consecutive characters that are the same? So abccef would also be deleted?

Answer (score 3):

use can user Regular Expression in Search and replace, match the pattern

for 
aaaa

aaab

aabb

abbb

Pattern is : **[ab]{4}**

select the Reg-ex option is search and replace and user this pattern

Answer (score 1):

Deleting lines found by searching can be done either by search and replace, or by doing a mark and delete.

For search and replace you would need to match the whole line plus the line end characters, then replace them with nothing. One interpretation of the original question would require searching for `^.*(aa|bb).*\r\n` with **Regular expression** selected and **dot matches newline** not selected. The `\r\n` part may need changing depending on the line ending style of the file.

For mark and delete select the **Mark** tab in the find window. Ensure **Bookmark line** and **Regular expression** are selected. Then, for the same interpretation as in the previous paragraph, enter the search text `aa|bb` and click on **Mark all**. Then select Menu => **Search** => **Bookmark** => **Remove bookmarked lines**.

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
search: (.)\1+
replace by: nothing
```

Comment: Searching for `(.)\1+` and replacing by nothing will merely delete any sequence of two or more of the same character. It will not delete the line.